# Black screen, can't install

Tags: installation, 12.10, uefi

Had a quick look around on here and around the web but I haven't been able to fix my problem yet.

I recently bought a new laptop with windows 8 pre installed on it but I want to be able to dual boot with ubuntu. I turned secure boot off in UEFI and I changed my load order so it would boot cd, USB then HDD. When I boot from my USB I get to a GRUB menu where I can choose to install or try ubuntu, no matter which one I select the screen goes black and stays that way. Left it for over half an hour the first time and nothing happened.

Trying to install ubuntu 12.10

Laptop is MSI GE60 288au with Intel Core i7-3630QM

*definately an issue with UEFI, when I boot in legacy mode it works fine, except it doesn't detect my already installed windows 8!

Comment: Could you please give more information on the laptop. eg. brand, model number

Comment: There was a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097308) in the forums back in December on this same issue. Another thread talking about specifics for NVidia GTX660M is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084614).